# WebView download opens browser window for a short moment before returning to WebView

Tags: android, download, android-intent, webview

My Problem is that when I hit the pdf link in the webview, the browser opens for a short moment (I guess to download the linked file), the pdf file starts to download and the app returns back to the webview. Is there a way to stop the browser window opening to start the download?

I have used WebViewClient to shouldOverrideUrlLoading so that clicked urls are kept in the webview:

```
private class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I have a download listener so I can download files  (for my needs these are pdf's):

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the MIME type to your `Intent` you use with `startActivity()` in your download listener.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see mimetype as the parameter for onDownloadStart, though I'm not sure how to use it in the body of the function. Ok, scratch that, I think I got it:     intent.setType(MIME_TYPE_PDF);

Comment: After adding the above line, I click the file link and as I have Adobe PDF Reader installed, it opens. But it seems the file has not been downloaded as it does not appear in the download folder or the pdf reader list.

Comment: @qubit: If you want to download it, you need to download it. This is no different than, say, viewing a PDF in IE or Chrome -- it comes up in the browser alone, and you need to take extra steps to actually save it. In the desktop browsers, the PDF plugin has a Save As option for this. I do not know if the Adobe Reader or other PDF viewers offer a similar facility (e.g., via the options menu). You may be better served doing the download yourself, storing it wherever you want it stored, then doing `ACTION_VIEW` on your stored copy.

Comment: For clarity, are you saying that there is no way to download the file in the webview without opening up the browser for a brief second? If I perform the same action in the browser, the file downloads from the same page I am viewing. There is no need for the browser to open a new blank tab/page like the webview does to download it.

Comment: @qubit: When I say "you need to download it", I mean by using `HttpClient` and doing so from Java. "If I perform the same action in the browser, the file downloads from the same page I am viewing." -- that is because the browser authors wrote Java code and downloaded it via `HttpClient` or something, presumably. All I can tell you is that `ACTION_VIEW` does not imply that an HTTP resource is permanently downloaded -- if that were the case, your phone would have run out of storage months ago. If you want the HTTP resource to be permanently downloaded, use `HttpClient` and download it.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's open browser for dowloading but i want to download in my own browser and i have no extendion or mime type i am dowloading pdf file liek on github i click on dowload but it automaticaly start downloading in that way my file is dowloading in browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare am able to download simple pdf but when it comes to secured websites, download listener never gets called. Please look at my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929878/unable-to-download-pdf-from-bank-websites-in-a-webview