# Unable to download pdf from bank websites in a webview

Tags: android, webview, download

I am creating an application for pdf download which is working fine with some links. I got a download listener in my code which works fine

```
  DownloadManager.Request request;
    request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    request.setDescription(mContext.getString(R.string.downloading_file));
    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, "/Dir", URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
    dm.enqueue(request);
```

but when it comes to downloading e-statement from ICICI bank or some other secured bank, download listener or `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` never get called.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet! changed the workflow